# vendor/bundle and ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I want to know if I'm doing incorrectly with rbenv and bundler.

I'm using `rbenv` and ruby 2.1.2, like so

```
rbenv versions
  system
* 2.1.2 (set by /home/deploy/cp/repo/.ruby-version)
```

I run

`bundle install --deployment --without=development,test --path=vendor/bundle`

from `/home/deploy/cp`

but get

`vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0`

created with all my gems.  Is there a versioning scheme I'm unaware of for bundler, or should I see a

`/home/deploy/cp/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.2`

dir?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've noticed this too, I just assumed it must just be a convention Bundler is using.  I have apps that have been upgraded from 1.9.3 to 2.1.2, and I have:

```
/path/to/shared/bundle
  /ruby
    /1.9.1
    /2.1.0
```

These machines have never had 1.9.1 or 2.1.0 installed, only 1.9.3 and 2.1.2.

edit: Ok so I dug for fun...  It comes from `RbConfig` in [`Bundler::Installer#generate_standalone`](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/installer.rb#L223):

```
(nick@thin)-(~)
(505)⚡️ ruby --version
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]

(nick@thin)-(~)
(506)⚡️ pry
[1] pry(main)> RbConfig::CONFIG['ruby_version']
=> "2.1.0"
```

Comment: Thanks for doing the pry debugging.  That's a nice way to prove your point.  If you use codepen, hit us up in support and I'll promo your account.