# Doing bundle --path uses wrong Ruby version

Tags: ruby, bundler

I'm using Ruby 2.2.2. When I do `bundle --path vendor/bundle` I get a folder called, strangely enough, `vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0`.

My Gemfile specifies Ruby 2.2.2. My `.ruby-version` specifies 2.2.2.

When I do `rvm list`, I get `=> ruby-2.2.2 [ x86_64 ]`. When I do `ruby -v`, I get `ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin14]`. I even uninstalled Ruby 2.2.0 and I still get the `2.2.0` folder when I do `bundle --path vendor/bundle`.

Why is it using Ruby 2.2.0 and how can I get it to use 2.2.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this before as well, I think this is likely the answer to your question:

[vendor/bundle and ruby version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874556/vendor-bundle-and-ruby-version)

You can verify this quickly in your rails console:

```
> Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.4)
> 2.1.2 :001 > RbConfig::CONFIG['ruby_version']  => "2.1.0"
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks, that does in fact give me `2.2.0`. So now that I know that, how do I change it so I get `2.2.2`?